# Android application crashes on load

Tags: java, android

This is a tricky one to explain. I have an android application currently deployed on 45-50 phones. I update a couple times a day and this seems to go okay, but without fail every day 1/2 phones will start going "App has stopped working please reopen" and won't stop until you reinstall the apk.

To error log I use a couple programs. These are both initiated at the top of my main activity.

Bugfender for logcat:

```
Bugfender.init(this, "KEY", BuildConfig.DEBUG);
        Bugfender.enableLogcatLogging();
        Bugfender.enableUIEventLogging(getApplication());
```

Bugsnag for the unhandled errors:

```
//Initialize bugsnag
Bugsnag.init(this);
```

I would have imagined one of these would pick up the error but bugsnag doesn't and bugfender is very hard to navigate to find the error.

Does anyone have any suggestions to debug this, I can't recreate so I really am struggling to find what this error is.

*NOT ON PLAYSTORE*

Comment: You can see the crash report from the Google Play Store crash analytics section as well. Can you please post the logcat from there please?

Comment: Will add to the post but it isn't on the playstore it's an internal application

Comment: Have you tried Crashlytics by Fabric ?

Comment: Provides the same as bugsnag so no dice

Comment: Fabric is very simple to understand